# Clang does not compile a g++ project

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, clang

When trying to compile a `g++` project with the `clang` compiler, there is a strange error showing up.

Here is the snippet of the source file:

```
std::set<TTransportNetworkId> l_transportNetworkIds;
SelectionResultContainer l_searchResult = p_repo.rootMoc() / LnAny("LNBTS") / LnAny("LNMME");

    BOOST_FOREACH(const SelectionResult & l_lnmmeSR, l_searchResult)
    {
        const MoLnmme & l_lnmme = l_lnmmeSR;
        l_transportNetworkIds.insert(*l_lnmme.transportNwId);
    }
```

The error message is:

```
conditional expression is ambiguous; 'rvalue_probe<Rrom::DataRep::SelectionResultContainer>' can be converted to 'Rrom::DataRep::SelectionResultContainer' and vice versa
BOOST_FOREACH(const SelectionResult & l_lnmmeSR, l_searchResult)
```

Conditions are:

- The file compiles fine with `gcc_4.3.2`
- `clang` in version 3.2 throws the above error
- Already tried to include the latest `boost` library which results in the same error

My guess is that `clang` handles rvalue conditions differently than this `gcc` version does.

`clang` is supposed to be a drop-in-replacement for `gcc`, so how can one get rid of this error without touching the source file?

Are there any options in `clang` which somehow disables these kind of errors?!

**UPDATE:**
I could create an example source file, which you can reproduce for yourself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class A : public std::vector<int>
{
public:
    template <class T>
    operator const T &() const;   
};

void foo(){
   A colA;
   int b = 1;
   BOOST_FOREACH(b, colA)
   {
        ;
   } 
}
```

When compiled with `clang 3.2` the above error is raised, with some additional insights to where exactly the error occurs:

```
error: conditional expression is ambiguous; 'rvalue_probe<A>' can be converted to 'A' and vice versa BOOST_FOREACH(b, colA)

expanded from macro 'BOOST_FOREACH' f (boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t BOOST_FOREACH_ID(_foreach_col) = BOOST_FOREACH_CONTAIN(COL))

expanded from macro 'BOOST_FOREACH_CONTAIN' BOOST_FOREACH_EVALUATE(COL)

expanded from macro 'BOOST_FOREACH_EVALUATE' (true ? boost::foreach_detail_::make_probe((COL), BOOST_FOREACH_ID(_foreach_is_rvalue)) : (COL))
```

This code is compiled without errors with `gcc_4.7.2`.
Any ideas why the two compilers behave differently?

Comment: you might consider posting a link to a [sscce](http://sscce.org) using [stacked-crooked](http://stacked-crooked.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this document, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/foreach.hpp

Snippet:

```
// Some compilers do not correctly implement the lvalue/rvalue conversion
// rules of the ternary conditional operator.
# if defined(BOOST_FOREACH_NO_RVALUE_DETECTION)
```

So, when providing a `-DBOOST_FOREACH_NO_RVALUE_DETECTION` definition option to clang, the error disappears.

Still the question remains whether gcc or clang is right or wrong on this point.

Comment: You could also use `std::for_each` or even a simple range-based for loop instead of relying on Boost for this.